# Install JanusGraph on Cassandra node/container or not

Tags: janusgraph

I want to test JanusGraph with Cassandra. Would you install it on the same node or in my case the same node. Any why or why not?

Thanks
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are testing JanusGraph with Cassandra using a small-medium graph (1M-10M elements) to get a feel for how the graph database works, then the [pre-packaged distribution](http://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/server.html#_using_the_pre_packaged_distribution) can suit your needs adequately. The pre-packaged distribution is a single zip file that you can [download](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/releases). It contains a script that will start a Cassandra node, an Elasticsearch node, and a Gremlin Server with `bin/janusgraph.sh start`. The pre-packaged distribution is not intended for production use.

If you are planning to test a production system or a large-huge graph (100M-1B elements), then you should consider using a Cassandra cluster.